# Using fgets and sscanf

Tags: c, parsing, fgets, scanf

So I'm making a calculator that takes a line of input. So like 1024 + 3024 + ...
I'm using fgets to store that line in one string. However, I don't know how to parse the string, not knowing how many inputs will come in. All I need is to know how to use sscanf to take my input string and be able to loop through and have it spit out a number/operator at a time. Then I use a stack to do the work based on it being a number or operator. Thank you.

Comment: This question is too broad.  Please see [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `sscanf`is primarily intended for parsing fixed-format input. You can use `strtok` to break the line into tokens, assuming that there are always spaces around the operators. Otherwise, you need to write a custom tokenizer.

Comment: It doesn't sound very suitable for sscanf; try strtol and manual string handling.

Comment: strtok() would be useful to you - as pointed out by user3386109, my bad. Another option might be to read input byte by byte using fgetc() for example, since your operators are likely mostly single characters like plus and minus, and some numeric input might be single characters also, it would certainly make this simpler than readin in a whole string then parsing that...but needs must.

Comment: `fgets()` is a good first step.  But there is a lot more to do.  Post your best code implementation so far.